# I labored it, but I can't it. How can I solve this integral?(trigonometric-integral)

Tags: analysis, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

$\int_0^\infty{x\tan x\over x^2+1}\cos(\tan^2x)\; dx$

I labored it, but I can't it. How can I solve this integral?

Comment: where is the labor ?

Answer (score 1):

The integrand has singularities at all odd multiples of $\pi/2$.  There's no way this thing converges.  I'm pretty sure that even just $\int_0^{\pi/2}$ diverges.

Comment: Good point, and since you are taking cos of infinity, its not just a pole, it seems to be an essential singularity.